# Convergence Of Probability Limits

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

$Let \left ( \Omega ,F,\mathbb{P} \right ) $
a probability space  $\Omega$  it is the set of all possible results of a randomized experiment. take two events $A$ y $B$, such that $\mathbb{P}\left ( B \right )\neq 0$ If the event takes place n times independently. Be $S_n$ the number of times a result belongs to $B$, within the $S_n$ results in $B$, $R_n$ of them are also in $A$, in which sense convergence and to which value  $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{R_n}{S_n}$

Comment: If you want to ask a new question, then you should add it as a new question instead of editing the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\frac{S_n}{n}$ can be seen as the average of i.i.d. variables with the same distribution as $1_B$, then the strong law of large number gives that $\frac{S_n}{n}$ converges almost surely to $E[1_B] = P(B)$.

Similarly if $R_n$ is the number of times that $A$ and $B$ occurs, then $\frac{R_n}{n}$ converges almost surely to $P(A\cap B)$, therefore 
$$ \frac{R_n}{S_n} = \frac{R_n/n}{S_n/n} \longrightarrow \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=P(A |B) $$
almost surely as $n\rightarrow \infty$.